# A function containing an another async function is not returning to the main function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've a function renderMe() that waits for an another function async fetchingTransactions() to return that in turn will be returned to the main render function. Unfortunately, async fetchintransactions is returning an array but it couldn't be utilized to be returned by renderMe().

What I'm trying to do is, because its a async fetchingtransactions is an async function, I tried to use await fetchingtransactions and .then to get the array but the main render function says that I'm returning an object which cannot be rendered.

```
async fetchingTransactions(){
 return '10'
}

renderMe(){
 this.fetchingtransactions().then((val) => {
 return(
  <View>
   <Text>Number is {val}</Text>
 </View>
 )
})
}

render(){
 return(
  <View>
   {this.renderMe()}
 </View>
 )
}
```

I expect the result to be a view having a text: "Number is 10". It's just an example and I'll be using real await fetch function in the async function but the following code is the basis of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `renderMe()` has no return statement, so it returns `undefined`
2. You could return the promise, but then `this.renderMe()` would give you a promise and not the `<View>` element

---

Render data, in the component, from the component's state.

```
render(){
 if (this.state.val !== undefined) {
  return(
   <View>
    <View>
     <Text>Number is {this.state.val}</Text>
    </View>
   </View>
  );
 } else {
   return something else;
 }
}
```

Call `fetchingtransactions`  and `then` *update the state*.

Comment: Yeh. Looks like there is no other option other than setting state. Thanks mate.